# Thymeleaf - if checked do something

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a simple table and I have checkbox inside that table. If checkbox is selected I want to display other features.

My code:

```
<table>
            <tr th:each="obj,iterationStatus  : ${objs}">
                <td th:text="${obj.name}"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="firstcheckbox"></td>
                <td th:if="isChecked">
                <!-- do something -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

How I do this without using javascript and backbean?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have two options, the first option you don't want but is not a bad option is using Javascript: creating a function called `isChecked`.

Otherwise, you can know if a checkbox is checked with `thymeleaf` in the case you are in a form which calls itself. You could do something like `if(firstcheckbox != null)` and, of course, your checkbox would have a value `<input type="checkbox" name="firstcheckbox" value="value">`. Finally, you must add as attribute in your model: `model.addAttribute("firstCheckbox", firstCheckbox);`